# Is it true that $1_{B} \ast \frac{1}{|\det S|}(1_{B} \circ S) \leq 1_{2B}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $B$ be a ball centered at the origin with radius 1 and let $S$ be an invertible linear transformation, is it true that $$1_{B} \ast \frac{1}{|\det S|}(1_{B} \circ S) \leq 1_{2B}$$
where here $2B$ is the ball centered at the origin with radius 2.

Comment: What do you mean with $\ast$ ?

Comment: @sigmabe: For two functions, I define $(f \ast g)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(y)g(x - y)\, dy$.

Comment: Not pointwise : consider for instance a diagonal transformation in $\mathbb R^2$ with factors $\lambda$ and $\frac{1}{\lambda}$.